# Having more than one Openlayers layer switcher associated to one map

Tags: javascript, layers, openlayers

I am developing an OpenLayers 3 web application were I would like to incorporate more than one Layer Tree alongside my map.

I have this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joshuadickerson92/mtwbs2dg/4/) set up that it has a map with multiple layers and one Layer Tree. I would like to duplicate the layer tree multiple (4) times and have a parameter (as per the one in each layer of the example) that then defines which Layer Tree the layer goes into.

I imagine it involves an extra if statement when building the layer tree at the bottom of the code, similar to the slider option already in there, but I don't seem to be able to make it work.

The solution should also ideally remove the "all layers" group at the top of each Layer Tree.

Comment: You can create manually layer list an arbitrary number of layers without the use of layer switcher.

Comment: Thanks @Samane, but would it be possible to do it the way outlined in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Be implemented with Java and `layer tree node` and primeFaces component.

[image: This is my layer list]

Comment: This answer points to nowhere. What this has to do with Openlayers?

Comment: I did wonder the same @JonatasWalker, very misleading.

Comment: @JonatasWalker I just wanted to say that we can implement it manually and then using openLayers to display layers, Using attributes visibility. 
Its the same `OpenLayers`!

Comment: @JoshuaDickerson Do not want you to have a few layers list?

Comment: @Samane yes i do